# Mongoose schema getter recursion

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having trouble understanding how to use a getter with a mongoose schema I'm using for an API.  I'm using the ipaddr.js module for the ipaddr methods.

I have this field defined in my schema:

```
ipv4_address: {
    type: Buffer,
    required: false,
    get: function () {
        //For debugging, actually want it returned
        console.log(this.ipv4_address.toString());
        },
        set: function (v) {
            return ipaddr.parse(v).toByteArray();
        },
        select: false,
        index: true
    }
```

I've set getters to true so that I can see what's going on in the console, ultimately I just want the ipv4_address returned in the JSON result.

```
ClientSchema.set('toObject', {
    getters: true
});
ClientSchema.set('toJSON', {
    getters: true
});
```

I understand that this line:

```
console.log(this.ipv4_address.toString());
```

causes the setter to be called recursively resulting in a RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.  The reason for this I understand completely.  If I were reading from _ipv4_address this wouldn't happen, but the schema defines the variable name.

This is apart of a REST API and I'd like the POSTs to write the ipv4_address as that field name.  I'd like the field name to be the same when GETing the result.

I'm just very confused on how I should get around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getter function is passed the current field value, so you don't need to pull it out of `this`, and you can avoid the recursion:

```
get: function (me) {
    //For debugging, actually want it returned
    console.log(me.toString());
},
```